# Import function from separate file in C++

Tags: c++, function, input, include

I am trying to import the "Exponent" function from library.cpp to main.cpp, but I am getting

error: no matching function for call to 'Exponent'

```
  else if (op == "**") {result =  Exponent(x,y);}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "library.cpp"
using namespace std;



int main() {
  int x;
  int y;
  int result;
  string op;
  
  cout << "CALCULATOR" << endl;
  cout <<"Enter two numbers then an operator" << endl;
  cout << "1st Number: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "2nd Number: ";
  cin >> y;
  cout << "Operator(+,-,*,/,**): ";
  cin >> op;

  if (op == "+") {result = x + y;}
  else if (op == "-") {result = x - y;}
  else if (op == "*") {result = x * y;}
  else if (op == "/") {result = x / y;}
  else if (op == "**") {result =  Exponent(x,y);}
  
  cout << x << " " << op << " " << y << " = " << result <<endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

library.cpp

```
int Exponent(int x,int y, int result) {
 for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
{
    return result = result + x * x;
}
   
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `#include "foo.cpp"` is nearly always wrong. You should define a header file `library.h` with just the function signature and include that.

Comment: You define `Exponent` with three arguments and call it with two. What do you expect the compiler to do for the third one?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of things wrong here.

Here's an exponent function that works

```
int Exponent(int x, int y) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this problem has nothing to do with 'importing'. Your `Exponent` function would not have worked even if it had been in `main.cpp`. Breaking large problems into smaller ones is a key part of programming. A better approach here would have been getting the function to work in `main.cpp` first, and only then trying to move it to a different cpp file. Try to solve one problem at a time, then when it doesn't work you have a better idea of where the problem is.